# VHDL: How to avoid writing to and reading from 2D array at the same time?

Tags: vhdl, ram

For something I work on, I must use an 2D array but I find it dangerous to write to and read from a certain memory location in the array at the same time. How can I control this situation?

When both reading and writing is necessary at the same time, I want to prioritize writing and instead of reading from that certain location, the old value should be kept in the signal to which I read from array and write.

Answer (score 1):

You are anxious not to tell us what you are working on. Also you do not tell us if this is ASIC or FPGA nor how big the memory is.

FPGA vendors have ready-made dual-ported memories where you can set the operating mode. They all offer three modes:
 1. write-before-read (This is what you are asking for?)
 2. read-before-write
 3. read-old, write-new

For small memories you can write your own but this website does not provide
'*please write my code for me*' service. You should try first and when you get stuck show us the code and where it goes wrong, then we can help you.

As last remark: I am not sure you need that behavior, mostly the read-old, write-new behavior is what is required. Alternative you find that read-write clashes doe not happen (FIFO) or double buffering is required. (e.g. BCH and FFT)

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing from the same memory position simultaneously is actually not a problem. If you use a dual port RAM this is exactly what you're doing.

```
architecture rtl of dpram is
type mem_type is array ((2** addr_width) - 1 downto 0) of
std_logic_vector(data_width - 1 downto 0);
signal mem : mem_type;

begin
process (clk)
-- Write memory.
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk) then
        if (write_en = '1') then
            mem(conv_integer(waddr)) <= din;
            -- Using write address bus.
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

process (clk) -- Read memory.
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        dout <= mem(conv_integer(raddr));
        -- Using read address bus.
    end if;
end process;
end rtl;
```

You have to take care tough in case e.g. you're storing 16bit data vectors in a 8bit Ram block. Means one dataset is split up into two cells. In this case you have to check data consistency.

Comment: it would be better if your example used numeric_std (an IEEE standard) vs using the older std_logic_arith (an open source package provided by a vendor).